# compile time string_view formatting and concatenation

Tags: c++, string, logging, formatting, compile-time

I am designing a logger using P7 Baical. By abstracting this library, I can log the message and the format through the functional macro.

```
#define LOG_ARGS __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__
#define LOG_INFO(component, message, ...) \
        do { \
        if (1) { \
            component.format_struct(message); \
            log_info(LOG_ARGS, message, ##__VA_ARGS__);} \
        } while(0)


int main() {
    LOG_INFO(Mystruct(1, 2), "test message %d", 100);

}
```

Before calling log_info function, message must be **"a val: 1, b val: 2  test message %d"**

As a new feature, I want this macro to take a structure, format the members in this structure and merge them with the message. I don't want to use std::string for cost reasons while doing this. maybe i can do it using string_view. (I am not sure)

What is the most efficient and best way to do this? Can I do this job in compile-time?

Mystruct design basically is here: (there is may different member with different data type)

```
struct Mystruct {
    Mystruct(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}

    int _a;
    int _b;

    //format_struct(std::string_view&) function will be added  here...
};
```

I tried using std::string then it works. But I don't want to use std::string cause of efficiency. In code log mechanism may be everywhere. So, actually I wonder I can do that in compile time or using std::string_view.
I just want to format and concatenate struct member values with message.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string_view` is a **non owning** view, just a pair of a pointer-to-const and a size. It doesn't hold a string. If you don't want to use `std::string`, your only other option is a raw `char` array.

```cpp
struct Mystruct {
    Mystruct(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}

    int _a;
    int _b;

    template<size_t size>
    int format_struct(char(&out)[size]) {
        return snprintf(out, size, "a val: %d, b val: %d", _a, _b);
    }
};

static char message[512]; // A large enough array

/* If something looks like a function, it should be a function! */
template<typename C, typename... Args>
void my_log_info(const char* file, const char* func, int line, C&& obj, const char* msg, Args&&... args) {
    int size = obj.format_struct(message);
    strcpy(message + size, msg);
    log_info(file, func, line, message, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

#define LOG_INFO(c, m, ...) my_log_info(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE_, c, m, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized later that struct members are not clear at compile time. So the runtime will also be clear. I guess this code won't work in this case. What method do you think would be most efficient for me to follow?

Comment: @EnesAygün Considering your structs are modified at runtime, the log message will also be generated at runtime. I just gave an example on how to achieve that: a member function that formats the message and a static char array that holds the string (to avoid allocations). That’s as efficient as it can get for your purposes.